# Scale out ASP.NET Web Api 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

I am currently evaluating NodeJS and Microsoft ASP.NET Web Api for a REST Api implementation which will handle heavy traffic and although I can see how NodeJS can be scaled out with various additional modules and technologies I cannot find an example of how you can do the same with ASP.NET Web Api.

What is the best way or technology to scale out and load balance the ASP.NET Web Api to multiple servers?

Answer (score 2):

You can scale out any Web Api applications, like you do with other ASP.Net application. You basically have two or more web servers and have a load balancer or traffic manager to handle request between them.

What is the best technology? Well, that is a matter of option.

My opinion is that the performance bottleneck is at the data layer. You should look at implementing some sort of in memory caching facility such as Redis to help with scalability there.

Comment: Also use of the async await pattern with newer versions of .Net will give the efficiencies closer to that of the event-driven architectures like NodeJS and Nginx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I am aware of the async await pattern and its on par performance with NodeJS. This is why I am aksing for a load balancing solution, because this is the the only thing that seems like a disadvantage of Web Api compared to Node.js. With NodeJs you have options like Nginx, Varnish HAProxy, Node.js Clusters, which are widely used and there is a decent amount of examples. Examples for Web Api load balancing is actually what I am after.

Comment: You can still use HAProxy for load balancing with WebAPI. It sits in front of the web servers and load balances the traffic. Have a look at the SO architecture, it uses a mix of technologies with ASP.Net - http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html

Comment: http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html

Comment: Surely there are complexities around scaling horizontally.  Token keys, application contexts etc.